# How to "fixed-top" a NavBar only when its not collapsed?

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I created a NavBar with Bootstrap 5. It works flawless, the only problem I havent fixed yet is the following:

When the user increases the size of his view to <300% it will trigger the collapse button to show up. If he goes up to 500% the collapsed NavBar will cover the whole screen and you cant see the bottom of the NavBar anymore. Now the problem: Because its fixed on top of the site, scrolling down wont do anything, so the user is forced to look at a cutted NavBar until he chooses a route.  I know its a rare szenario, but there are probably a few solutions for that. Maybe you create a new custom layout for the collapsed NavBar or you restrict the "fixed-top" to only the not collapsed state. But I have no idea whats the best solution, and how to implement that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTPa3.jpg

````
<html>

<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type="text/css">
    
/* BANNER*/
.bg-steel {
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* BRAND */
.site-header .brand {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 300%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* ROUTES */
.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 250%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top py-0 my-0">

<!-- Navbar Left Side -->

        <div class="container d-flex bd-highlight">
                    <a class="navbar-brand mr-4 brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">MyWebsite</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row flex-wrap bd-navbar-nav pt-2 py-md-0">

                            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md-auto">
                                <a class="nav-link p-2" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md-auto">
                                <a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Docs</a>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                    
<!-- Navbar Right Side -->

                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row flex-wrap ms-md-auto">

                        <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md-auto">
                            <a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Register</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    
              </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: I pasted your code in a codepen.io and looks well (not as your image). See if you have any other style or code in your app that is affecting your navbar. Or test it in codepen.io

Comment: You can replace `fixed-top` with a custom `fixed-top-lg` class by adding a media query to your custom CSS and copying the styles from Bootstrap’s `fixed-top.` You’ll need to add something like `mt-0 mt-lg-5` to the first section below your navbar so that it positions properly with the navbar positioned relatively and absolutely. You probably don’t need to worry too much about a user viewing your site at 500%. People who need that kind of enlargement will probably be using a browser like [Webbie](https://www.webbie.org.uk/webbrowser/) rather than Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Thanks for your answer. What do I have to edit in the custom fixed-top-lg to solve my problem ? Do you mean I should add mt-0 mt-lg-5 to the whole content section below the navbar?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the top, normally you apply Bootstrap's `fixed-top` class. Since you want the top to only be fixed when it's expanded, you can create a custom `fixed-top-lg` class (or sm or md - your choice).

And you'll need spacing for the section or container below your navbar to maintain the spacing - see the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    @media (min-width:992px) {
        .fixed-top-lg {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:1030;
        }
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<section class=" vh-100 bg-info mt-0 mt-lg-5">
    <div class="container pt-lg-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p>Content below the navbar &mdash; included to show the spacing that&rsquo;s needed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post worked for me, [source](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Navbar Stickied to the Top</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-5 bg-warning">
        <h1>Demo Header</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Profile</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1">Reports</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Demo Content -->    
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
            <h1>Sticky Top Navbar</h1>
            <p class="lead">The static-top navbar scrolls with the page until it reaches the top, then stays there.</p>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.Quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus. Tibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed.</p>
        <p>Orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. Phasellus vitae convallis ligula, nec volutpat tellus. Vivamus scelerisque mollis nisl, nec vehicula elit egestas a. Sed luctus metus id mi gravida, faucibus convallis neque pretium. Maecenas quis sapien ut leo fringilla tempor vitae sit amet leo. Donec imperdiet tempus placerat. Pellentesque pulvinar ultrices nunc sed ultrices. Morbi vel mi pretium, fermentum lacus et, viverra tellus. Phasellus sodales libero nec dui convallis, sit amet fermentum sapien auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed eu elementum nibh, quis varius libero.Nam eget purus nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliquet. Praesent luctus hendrerit arcu non laoreet. Morbi consequat placerat magna, ac ornare odio sagittis sed. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
        <p>Pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim. Donec sed nibh vitae lorem porttitor blandit in nec ante. Pellentesque vitae metus ipsum. Phasellus sed nunc ac sem malesuada condimentum. Etiam in aliquam lectus. Nam vel sapien diam. Donec pharetra id arcu eget blandit. Proin imperdiet mattis augue in porttitor. Quisque tempus enim id lobortis feugiat. Suspendisse tincidunt risus quis dolor fringilla blandit. Ut sed sapien at purus lacinia porttitor. Nullam iaculis, felis a pretium ornare, dolor nisl semper tortor, vel sagittis lacus est consequat eros. Sed id pretium nisl. Curabitur dolor nisl, laoreet vitae aliquam id.Nullam hendrerit justo non leo aliquet imperdiet. Etiam in sagittis lectus. Suspendisse ultrices placerat accumsan. Mauris quis dapibus orci. In dapibus velit blandit pharetra tincidunt. Quisque non sapien nec lacus condimentum facilisis ut iaculis enim. Sed viverra interdum bibendum. Donec ac sollicitudin dolor. Sed fringilla vitae lacus at rutrum. Phasellus congue vestibulum ligula sed consequat.</p>
        <p>Enim arcu, interdum vel metus dignissim, venenatis feugiat purus. Nulla posuere orci ut leo sodales, sed cursus dolor ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam sit amet quam orci. Nulla sollicitudin lectus eget posuere venenatis. Sed vestibulum elementum sagittis. Quisque tristique tortor quis feugiat sollicitudin. Ut pellentesque luctus vulputate. Ut at odio ac erat blandit vehicula ut eget urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam ut iaculis nibh, eget eleifend elit.Convallis eget pretium eu, bibendum non leo. Proin suscipit purus adipiscing dolor gravida, in fermentum sapien blandit. Praesent pellentesque ligula dui, in gravida turpis vehicula ac. Pellentesque hendrerit nunc ut luctus hendrerit. Aliquam nec tincidunt urna. Ut interdum nec odio non interdum. Curabitur ligula justo, dapibus non ligula tristique, dapibus tristique nulla. Aliquam pulvinar dapibus eros, rutrum pretium urna iaculis ut. Nam est est, tempus id egestas et, viverra in dui. Aliquam gravida orci tortor, sed congue justo ornare vel. Cras in quam consectetur eros varius scelerisque. Ut vel fermentum purus. Nullam interdum blandit turpis, id pellentesque massa feugiat at. Ut sed lectus lectus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla rutrum, ante quis convallis ultricies, magna quam rhoncus erat, in lacinia libero magna a ipsum.</p>
        <p>Fusce enim arcu, interdum vel metus dignissim, venenatis feugiat purus. Nulla posuere orci ut leo sodales, sed cursus dolor ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam sit amet quam orci. Nulla sollicitudin lectus eget posuere venenatis. Sed vestibulum elementum sagittis. Quisque tristique tortor quis feugiat sollicitudin. Ut pellentesque luctus vulputate. Ut at odio ac erat blandit vehicula ut eget urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam ut iaculis nibh, eget eleifend elit.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```